# Am I correct in finding the volume in this stereometric problem?

Tags: geometry

**Prerequisite**

The distance between the two balls is 6 cm. The distance from the centre of the first ball to the centre of the second ball is 12 cm. The radius of the first ball is twice the radius of the second. Find the volume of the ball with the smaller radius

**My solution**

Make an equation according to the condition of the problem:

$12=6+R_1+R_2,\\ 
12=6+2R_2+R_2,\\
3R_2=6,\\
R_2=2$

$R_2$ is the radius of the smaller ball, we can find its volume: $V=\frac{4}{3}πR^3=\frac{4}{3}*π*2^3=10\frac{2}{3}π$

Comment: It looks fine and correct!

Comment: What about this solution leaves you unsure? Please elaborate in an [edit]. As it stands, this question lacks context.